# where in angular.js source code is dom traversal?

Tags: angularjs, dom

I am assuming that angular.js traverses the DOM on the 'DOMContentLoaded' event (or something like that). That's the only way I know that angular could find all arbitrary locations of ng- attributes. Also, from the example here (https://angularjs.org/#the-basics) it looks like angular js dynamically finds all locations of `{{` in the page, so does it also traverse into every single text node and search for that string?

Is that how angular accomplishes its magic? If so, where in angular.js source code does that happen?

Comment: Probably you should have a look at the [interpolator](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/interpolate.js). At least there you can set the start and end markups.

Answer (score -1):

The `{{` or `}}` are part of angular's interpolation. If you search in the angular.js file for interpolateProvider, you get a lot of comments with information regarding this.